# Problema con PYTTSX3 (Pasar de texto a voz)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, python-3.7

Estoy intentando crear un programa que escucha lo que digo ( esto funciona bien ) y después me devuelve mi palabra en audio ( esto no me funciona del todo ). Estoy usando la librería Pytssx3, y el problema viene en que el programa es capaz de hacer esta acción una vez, pero no entiendo por qué, no entra al bucle.

Creo que el problema está en el comando "engine.RunAndWait", como su nombre indica, se queda esperando (runandWAIT). Aquí os dejo el código, muchas gracias.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
import pyttsx3


def hablando(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()  


def callback(recognizer, audio):

        text = r.recognize_google(audio, language = "es-ES")   
        print("Creo que has dicho " + text)
        hablando(text)


    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("No puedo entenderte")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("No hay resultados para el sistema de reconocimiento de Google; {0}".format(e))




#Creando la voz

engine = pyttsx3.init()                         #Iniciando el método
rate= engine.getProperty("rate")                #Ajustando la velocidad 
engine.setProperty("rate", 135)

volume = engine.getProperty("volume")           #Ajustando el volumen
engine.setProperty("volume", 1)

engine.say("Ajustando micrófono")
engine.runAndWait()
voice = engine.getProperty("voices")            #Seleccionando voces
engine.setProperty("voices", voice[0].id) 




r = sr.Recognizer()     #r reconoce la voz
m = sr.Microphone()     #m es el micrófono



# Escucha 5 segundos para ajustar el ruido ambiental   

with sr.Microphone() as source:   
     r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)  
     r.dynamic_energy_threshold = True






stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)


for _ in range(50): time.sleep(0.1)

while True: time.sleep(0.1)
```

La parte de más importancia es la función "callback", ahí es donde llamo a la función "hablando" pasándole la variable "text" con lo que tiene que decir.

Como os digo, esto lo hace bien una vez, pero después es imposible crear un bucle. GRACIAS.

Comment: Jey, alguien tenía un problema similar en SO, dicen que se le arregló instalando pyaudio (`pip install pyaudio`), podrías intentarlo

Comment: Gracias aunque a mí eso no me funcionó, volví a escribirlo de 0 siguiendo otra lógica y no sé por qué, ahora sí funciona, si el código puede interesarle a alguien no tengo problemas en postearlo.